# A better workflow with Gulp Wordpress and Dropbox

Tags: wordpress, gulp, dropbox

My current workflow when building a Wordpress site is to create the project in a dropbox folder (so it gets backed up). I then push to a remote REPO.
My problem is that although I can gitignore the GULP dependencies for the repo, I cannot with Dropbox. Each project can generate 500,000 files (albeit tiny), and this really breaks dropbox - for DAYS!
Am I missing something? possible solutions?

1. Create the project outside dropbox - rely on the repo as a backup :(
2. Create the project outside dropbox - then clone repo back into DB (without GULP dependencies)?
3. Install dependencies globally? (npm install -g) - problem is all projects using the same dependencies isn't always what I want.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't using GitHub for backups? you can always revert to an old commit if you need to.

Comment: I totally rely on GIT for version control, but as a backup solution? is it robust enough? For example Bitbucket only keeps 5 days of backups purely for DR.

Comment: I guess it depends on what all you are needing to back up. I feel git is sufficient for code backups, but if you need database backups or image backups a server-side solution might be better. Wordmove is also a pretty nice tool that automatically creates database backups, and you could potentially use it to push files to dropbox, excluding dependency folders.